# Install datatables for laravel 7 with webpack

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-7, laravel-mix

I'm trying to install jquery datatables for laravel 7 with npm and webpack.

I installed it like this via cmd,

```
npm install --save datatables.net-bs4
```

This code ran successfully without an error and I added this `resources/js/bootstrap.js`

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
    require('datatables.net-bs4');
} catch (e) {}
```

Added this in `resources/sass/app.scss`

```
@import '~datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css';
```

Then ran `npm run dev` in terminal. But when I call datatables I'm getting.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

I call datatables in view like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('table').DataTable();
});
 </script>
```

All Npm commands ran successfully without any errors. It would be great help if someone can help

Comment: Can you add the bootstrap.js code (in the resources folder) and the code where you call the datatables instance?

Comment: @camrymps I added the code

Comment: Thanks. In your view (where you call the DataTable function), have you included your app.js (something like <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>) file before the DataTable function call?

Comment: @camrymps Yes I added `<script src="{{ url('/') }}/js/app.js"></script>`

Comment: According to the documentation for the datatables package, it looks like you need to pass the jQuery instance to it on the require. window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); require( 'datatables.net-bs4' )( $ );

Comment: @camrymps tried that too but didn't work :'(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer. Seems like the place I have added `require('datatables.net-bs4');` was wrong. instead of `resources/js/bootstrap.js` I added it inside `resources\assets\js\app.js` file like this and it started working.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
require('datatables.net-bs4');
```

Since all other codes are imports I added as an import like this

```
import 'datatables.net-bs4';
```

After I ran `npm run dev` and it started working. Keeping the answer since anyone else came up with the same issue.